# A fly stationed at a point on the circumference of the base of a cylindrical tower of radius $12$ feet

Tags: geometry

I was helping a somebody on a problem when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> A fly stationed at a point on the circumference of the base of a cylindrical tower of radius $12$ feet. Find that he can just see a distant flagstaff by walking along the tangent line to the base either a distance $8$ feet in one direction or $5$ feet in the other direction. Find the distance of the foot of the flagstaff from the center of the base of the tower.

**My work**

This is what I imagined...

[image: (Tower1)]

Adding some finer details...

[image]

We see the figure above that...

$$x^2 = 4^2 + z^2$$
$$y^2 = 7^2 + z^2$$

Then...

$$x^2 = 4^2 + (y^2 - 7^2)$$
$$x^2 = y^2 - 33$$
$$x^2 - y^2 = -33$$

I guess I'm stuck. We got one equation and two unknowns. How to answer the above question?

Comment: You've got the fly **on top of** the tower, whereas the fly is in fact **at the base of** the tower, and when it walks it *leaves* the tower, not walks along the top of it..

Comment: @AakashM I thought the fly is on top of tower, which happens to be an upper base of cylindrical tower.....

Comment: It looks like there is a mistake in the problem. The fly supposedly sees the flagstaff from different sides of the tower at points located 13 feet apart, but the diameter of the tower is 24 feet. Have you perhaps copied the numbers wrong? Or maybe12 feet is the diameter rather than the radius?

Comment: A tangent line touches a circle at just one point and is outside the circle everywhere else, so while walking on the tangent line the fly cannot be standing over the interior of the tower. Also, there's no reason to think that there is _any_ point on top of the tower's base from which the flagstaff is not visible; no other objects have been specified that could obstruct the view. And if the view is obstructed by some object not described in the problem statement, the geometry could be almost anything. Altogether it makes no sense for the fly to walk on top of the tower.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen I properly copied it. When I searched the same problem on the internet, I have the same question on other sites. But none of them has an answer. This might be the first time the problem above will be answered.....soon...

Comment: @DavidK A fly walking through the tangent line while going to the center of the cylindrical tower? Maybe it means a fly crossing through the tangent line on the side of tower while going to the center of the cylindrical tower. Even other sites doesn't have an answer to the problem above.  We'll persists...

Comment: The problem statement says "along the tangent line". Not through, not across. If the person writing this problem meant for the fly to walk anywhere other than upon the tangent line itself, the problem is incorrectly written. It seems in any case that if your transcription is accurate, the problem was incorrectly written, because the things it describes cannot all happen in the same model.

Comment: I have posted an answer to the problem. You may not like the answer, but I believe it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following figure is a view of the tower from above.

[image]

The shaded disk is the base of the tower.
Point $F$ is the starting point of the fly on the circumference of the base of the tower.
The fly is constrained to walk along a line tangent to the base of the tower; the only such line that includes the fly's starting position is the line
$GFH.$
The points $G$ and $H$ are respectively $8$ feet from the fly's starting position in one direction along the tangent line and $5$ feet from the fly's starting position in the other direction along the tangent line.

Region $A$ (including line $GFH$ and all points to its left)
contains points all of which are visible from $F,$ $G,$ $H,$ and any point between those points; no point in that region is "just" visible from either $G$ or $H.$
Points in regions $B$ and $C$ are not visible from $H$;
points in regions $C$ and $D$ are not visible from $G.$
No point is "just" visible from $G$ and "just" visible from $H,$
so there is no point at which a flagpole can be placed that satisfies the conditions in the problem statement.

**Conclusion: *The statement of this problem is a mistake.***
It has no solution.

Comment: I suspect someone wrote "radius" instead of "diameter".

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen I think so too. In fact I think that is the mistake in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen I guess the problem is ugly. No answer. No wonder other sites having this question still remained unanswered......

Comment: @DavidK The question sucks......unanswerable....We'll condemn this question to oblivion.....:-D

Comment: Googling "just see a distant flagstaff" suggests that this problem has as its source ['Solid Mensuration, With Proofs', Kern& Bland (1938)](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Solid_Mensuration.html?id=Y6cAAAAAMAAJ), which in turn got the *general* problem (with numbers $r$, $p$, $q$) from "Advanced Trigonometry - Durell & Robson (1930)". This earlier book asked the reader to come up with a general formula, but Kern and Bland appear to have used specific values that don't make sense. I wonder what the 'proof' given by them for this problem is!